# drawing a model on a slope

Tags: opengl, geometry

My models are axis-aligned.

I know the normal of the surface I want to draw them on; how do I compute the rotations or rotation matrix that I should use to draw the model perpendicular to the surface?

Comment: What is the context? What do you need? Do you need the math to transform all vertices of your model to a new location, do you just want to draw it in some rendering pipeline, do you just want to understand the maths behind it? What is your question?

Comment: I want to set up the GL modelview matrix so that I can draw my model in its VBO on the face (I know the xyz) and colinear to the normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if **u** is the unit up vector, and **n** is the unit surface normal, then you want a rotation that turns **u** into **n**. (This rotation isn't unique: you can compose any rotation about **u** before it, and any rotation about **n** after it.)

How to compute this rotation? Well, it depends on what framework or API you're working with, and how rotations are represented. A decent framework has an API call for this, for example in Unity 3D there's [`Quaternion.FromToRotation`](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html).

If you don't have an API call for that, then you can work it out for yourself. [Any rotation can be represented in axis–angle form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_rotation_theorem), say (**a**, θ). Here θ is the angle between the vectors **u** and **n** (which you can compute using the [cosine rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines#Vector_formulation): **u** · **n** = |**u**| |**n**| cos θ), and **a** is an axis perpendicular to both vectors: **a** = **u** × **n**. (There are two special cases: when **u** = **n** the null rotation will do, and if **u** = −**n** any half-rotation about any vector perpendicular to **u** will do.)

If you're using OpenGL you can now call [`glRotate`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRotate.xml).

And if you don't even have that ... well, you've no business asking this kind of basic question! But [see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) for how to turn axis–angle representation into matrix representation.

Comment: In XNA, you could do this [sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/collision_3d_heightmap_normals). The sample also contains a little piece of documentation in `HTML`-form

Comment: I see that XNA [lacks an API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.quaternion_members.aspx) for computing a rotation between two vectors. I'm not impressed!